# How to run ionic app on my mobile device?

Tags: ionic-framework

I found one answer "adb devices"commend to know list of devices attached.But my doubt is where to type this commend and how to know my android SDK paths connecting with ionic .please exp in detail

Answer (score 1):

1.) [Enable debugging over USB](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html)

2.) Install drivers for mobile device

3.) Run `adb devices` in **cmd.exe**

[image]

```
$ ionic platform add android
$ ionic run android
```

---

[Chapter 2: Installation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html)

> Windows users developing for Android: You'll want to make sure you
>   have the following installed and set up.
>
> *NOTE: Whenever you make changes to the PATH, or any other environment
>   variable, you'll need to restart or open a new tab in your shell
>   program for the PATH change to take effect.*
>
> Java JDK
>
> Install the most recent [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) (NOT just the JRE).
>
> Next, create an environment variable for `JAVA_HOME` pointing to the
>   root folder where the Java JDK was installed. So, if you installed the
>   JDK into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7`, set `JAVA_HOME` to be this path.
>   After that, add the JDK's `bin` directory to the PATH variable as well.
>   Following the previous assumption, this should be either
>   `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` or the full path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin`
>
> Apache Ant
>
> To install Ant, download a zip from [here](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), extract it, move the first
>   folder in the zip to a safe place, and update your PATH to include the
>   bin folder in that folder. For example, if you moved the Ant folder to
>   `c:/`, you'd want to add this to your PATH: `C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin`.
>
> Android SDK
>
> Installing the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is also necessary. The Android SDK provides
>   you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test,
>   and debug apps for Android.
>
> Cordova requires the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to be set. This
>   should point to the `[ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk` directory (for
>   example `c:\android\android-sdk`).
>
> Next, update your PATH to include the `tools/` and `platform-tools/`
>   folder in that folder. So, using ANDROID_HOME, you would add both
>   `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` and `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`.

Comment: When I am running adb devices commend,it is not showing my device ... But I am installed my driver software for my mobile device..In this case What I do ?

Comment: Run `android update adb` then `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`. Also, when you connect your phone to computer be sure to enable connection in popup which will show on mobile device.

Comment: still I am not getting.